# UWP C# Convert png to a pdf

Tags: c#, pdf, uwp, png

Not sure if there is an easy thing out there for this. Is there a way so convert a png to a pdf file in a UWP program? I've got a program that reads in a lot of images and I'd like to edit them, then output as a pdf. I just need to convert a 1280 x 720 png file into a landscape pdf in the same location with the same file name so hopefully this could be done without the user needing to input too much.

I'm not really sure where to start on this.

Any pointers to anything relevant would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First google result:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/26b237/insert-an-image-to-pdf-in-C-Sharp/

Not promoting the component, but it shows how it is done. You create a .pdf document and load the image into it with desired styles and save the document.

[image]

We usually do not propose solutions (there are multiple ways). Rather we help you along the way - you should try something yourself, and when you get stuck then show what you tried.

Comment: Thanks for this. I did search for "UWP C# Convert png to pdf" and the results were all pdf to png. Apparently my googling was substandard. This seems to work ok. It's given me the what I wanted which is great.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the nuget package **PdfSharp**, it's the best library for C#

http://www.pdfsharp.net

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Windows has native conversion of image to PDF (but you need to make the connections via the shell) and control is limited

So here 1280 x 720 image.png  will by default need A3 but I could change that in windows forms.

[image]

using command

```
rundll32 "C:\WINDOWS\system32\shimgvw.dll" ImageView_PrintTo "c:\mydata\1280 x 720.png" "My Print to PDF"
```

I cheated by having "My Print to PDF" (A3 - headless) duplicate "Microsoft Print to PDF" (A4 - prompting) but with scripting could have set a custom 1280 x 720 page size.

IF (big if) you want 1 page PDF with imbedded image that's in a %PDF-... %EOF wrapper you could do that with the simplest of text prefix and suffix strings, possibly even string pages together. However its much simpler to use any cli PDF manipulator to do that for you such as https://www.win2pdf.com/doc/command-line-png-to-pdf.html and UWP is a big overhead thus usually includes more functions than you need.

Disclaimer I support SumatraPDF which is **one portable exe that can headless command line print PNG folder.zip to Multi page Images.pdf** However for a PNG quality approach would need manual "save as" PDF scripting not hidden printer commands.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> UWP C# Convert png to a pdf

For this scenario, the better way is call Print api to print png to pdf with Microsoft Print to PDF printer . You could refer to document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/print-from-your-app). And we also provide printer helper for printing quickly. For more detail please refer [printhelper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/helpers/printhelper).